# ExchangeService: connecting without credentials, how to retrieve user information?

Tags: c#, exchange-server

I am analyzing a users Exchange mailbox with calls to the ExchangeService. This tool needs to run on the client environment periodically and by ommiting the credentials to the service I am connecting to the Exchange Service as the logged in Windows User. I can succesfully loop thrue the folders and items.

Now I want tot retrieve the information about the mailbox being used. Username and (main) E-mail should suffice. But I cannot find anything about how to retrieve this information. Every example provides credentails for the user, or auto-discovering the Exchange service from the e-mail adres. I do not want the user to configure anything :-).

Any suggestions?

```
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1);
service.Url = new Uri("https://FQDN/EWS/Exchange.asmx");
???
FindItemsResults<Item> findResults = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.SentItems, new ItemView(100)); // this works
```

I've tried using service.ResolveName, but that can give multiple answers, even using Environment.UserName

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest method to do this is to use ConvertId operation and use unresolvable address (blah@blah.com always works for me) in the Mailbox element. Exchange should convert this to the actual Mailbox in the response. eg

```
        Folder chk = Folder.Bind(service, WellKnownFolderName.Inbox);
        AlternateId aiItem = new AlternateId();
        aiItem.Mailbox = "Blah@Blah.com";
        aiItem.UniqueId = chk.Id.UniqueId;
        aiItem.Format = IdFormat.EwsId;
        String CasServer = service.Url.Host.ToString();
        AlternateIdBase caid = service.ConvertId(aiItem, IdFormat.HexEntryId);
        Console.WriteLine(((AlternateId)caid).Mailbox);
```

Cheers
Glen